# how to replace [*] with \command{*} in TeXworks?

Tags: texworks

I have the following lines in my document :

```
[Ctrl + r] : ..............
[Ctrl + u] : ..............
...
[Ctrl + m] : ..............
```

What I want (using **TeXworks** replacement wizard) is to replace all the string matching the pattern **[*]** by **\mycommand{$1}** so the lines becomes :

```
\mycommand{Ctrl + r} : ..............
\mycommand{Ctrl + u} : ..............
...
\mycommand{Ctrl + m} : ..............
```

*How should I proceed ?*

Comment: Use `emacs`, it has a `replace-regexp` command.

Comment: @cgnieder not if i replace only the selection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeXworks can replace regular expressions. Use Search->Replace from the menu (or Ctrl+R), then put `\[Ctrl ([^]]*)\]` in the "Replace" field and `\mycommand{Ctrl \1}` in the "With" field, and in addition activate the "Regular expression" checkbox.

Pressing "Replace" or "Replace all" will give the desired result.

Comment: Don't you need to use `\\mycommand{Ctrl \1}` in the "With" field?

Comment: @ChaitanyaTappu It works with one backslash and with two, but the latter could be safer, you're right.