# How to change $$ $$ to \[ \]

Tags: math-mode, texworks

I have a long math file where `$$ $$` was used for display math. I want to change these to `\[ \]` to make it look neater. I don't know whether I can use the find/replace function in TeXworks to alternate between replacing by `\[ and \]`, and I'm not enough of a programmer to solve this with a batch program.

Is there an easy fix?

Comment: This is perhaps a job better suited for `sed` or `perl`. I am sure, there are scripts for this on the net, which can be called from TeXWorks. Welcome to TeX.SX by the way;-)

Comment: You could also do it with Python (see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951660/how-to-replace-the-first-occurrence-of-a-regular-expression-in-python)). You can search with your favorite search engine using the keywords _language (python, perl, etc.)_ and _replace odd occurrences_ (or _alternating string replace_). But depending on the length of you document, it could be worth doing it by hand.

Comment: Try `regular expressions`. Are you on a windows system?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy answer without programming. I think if you use find/replace this way: find/replace ($$ with \\[ ) on every other case (manually clicking to the other case) and then ending with find/replace all ($$ with \\]) it wouldn't take that long. A lot of mindless clicking though...

Comment: A related posting: [Can I get $$…$$ to behave like \\[…\\]?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240139/5001) If you can run LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX, you may be able to leave all `$$` unchanged -- and let a Lua function replace the `$$` symbols intelligently, "on the fly", with either `\[` or `\]`.

Comment: If you use [vim](http://www.vim.org) then you can define two macros, `one` and `two`, so that `one` changes the next `$$` to `\[` and calls `two` and then `two` changes the next `$$` to `\]` and calls `one`. You can also use multi-line regular expressions but they are more prone to fail on corner cases.

Comment: Texworks can find and replace regular expressions, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99703/how-to-replace-with-command-in-texworks